# How do I use html5 Color input type in wicket framework

Tags: java, scala, wicket

In the wicket application, I want to apply some style and color in my form. So for that I want to use `< input wicket:id="fillColorField"  class="input" type="color"/>` instead of `input wicket:id="fillColorField"  class="input" type="text"/>` in .html file.

Is there any attribute or element for html5 Color input type in the wicket framework like for `type= "text"` we have `TextField<~>`?

If there is no such attribute then please suggest me the alternative way to do this but it should be html5 color input type, not others like javascript color picker, etc.

Comment: Please clarify.

Comment: @zixuan please see the updated description.

Comment: Wait. For a guess, I would say *NO*.

Comment: @zixuan No for what

Comment: I don't think there are any attributes to actually do this.

Comment: then there must be an alternative way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Color as Hex-String

The simplest way is to use a normal `TextField<String>` and overwrite the `getInputTypes` method which tells wicket to accept your `type="color"` in your HTML for the input.

```
IModel<String> colorModel = new Model<>();
queue(new TextField<String>("colorpicker", colorModel) {
            @Override
            protected String[] getInputTypes() {
                return new String[] {"color"};
            }
        });
queue(new Label("colorlabel", colorModel));
```

With this you will have the string representation of the color in your model, like the browser sends it, so for example `#FF33AA`.

**You might also want to add a validator or some other safeguard to the TextField which checks the format, as it's not guaranteed that the submitted value will always be a nicely formatted color hex-string (browsers not supporting `type="color"`, a malicious user sending arbitrary values, etc.)!**

---

### Color as Java Object

Additionally you could also register a custom `IConverter` in your wicket `Application` that converts the String value to something more useful, for example a `java.awt.Color` object, which would give you direct access to the RGB values.

For this add a new converter for the `Color` class in your wicket Application class by overwriting the `Application#newConverterLocator()` method:

```
@Override
protected IConverterLocator newConverterLocator() {
    ConverterLocator defaultLocator = new ConverterLocator();

    defaultLocator.set(Color.class, new IConverter<Color>() { 
        @Override
        public Color convertToObject(String value, Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
            try {
                return Color.decode(value);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConversionException("Illegal color format", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String convertToString(Color value, Locale locale) {
            return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", value.getRed(), value.getGreen(), value.getBlue());
        }
    });

    return defaultLocator;
}
```

And then use a Model with the Color class instead of String.

```
IModel<Color> colorModel = new Model<>();
queue(new TextField<Color>("colorpicker", colorModel, Color.class) {
            @Override
            protected String[] getInputTypes() {
                return new String[] {"color"};
            }
        });
queue(new Label("red", colorModel.map(Color::getRed)));
queue(new Label("green", colorModel.map(Color::getGreen)));
queue(new Label("blue", colorModel.map(Color::getBlue)));
```

Comment: Ok nice answer but cannot directly use HTML5 color picker currently as it always has a value (defaults to black) which contrasts with Style which has Option[Color] as value